# SVG: border outline для группы элементов

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Я хотел бы добавить границу для элементов, которые сгруппированы.

В качестве примера:

```
<g id="group">
  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="orange" />
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
</g>
```

При наилучшем варианте, граница должна выглядеть, как рисунке.
Расстояние между элементами и границей не требуется (но лучше её иметь).
Основной целью должна быть единая граница  вокруг элементов группы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел изображение [в учебнике](https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/introduction-to-custom-svg-charting-using-mvc-and-razor), но там  просто продемонстрировано, как может выглядеть группа элементов. Так что, это не помогает.

Я уже пробовал разные решения, но ни одно из них не работает, как ожидалось, например:

- Фильтр SVG с использованием `feColorMatrix` и `feMorphology` (см.
  этот пост). Но в этом случае цвет элементов изменяется при применении
  фильтра.
- Стилизация с `stroke` и `stroke-width` приводит к прямоугольной рамке
  вокруг группы, что тоже не то, что я хочу.

*Какие есть идеи, как получить границу вокруг группы, как показано на картинке?*

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49693471/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Трудно получить `dashed stroke`, показанную на картинке, которую вы предоставили. Но сплошной контур сделать возможно.

Вот пример:

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="8" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="10" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="1 0 0 0 0
                             0 1 0 0 0
                             0 0 1 0 0
                             0 0 0 .3 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="orange" />
    <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Ниже, как это работает:**

`<feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha" radius="8" result="e1" />`

Фильтр `feMorphology` использует [dilate](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feMorphologyElement) (расширенную) операцию для  утолщения графических элементов.

Используется исходный альфа канал в качестве входного изображения, это приводит к появлению черных областей, соответствующих графическим элементам изображения, и белого цвета в остальных частях.

`<feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha" radius="10" result="e2" />`

Используя  тот же фильтр снова, но с большим количеством `dilation`, что приводит к слегка более плотному изображению, и это приводит к появлению черных областей, соответствующих графическим элементам изображения, и белого цвета в остальных частях.

`<feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor" result="outline"/>`

Эти расширенные результаты объединяются с использованием операции XOR, которая оставляет черный контур.

`<feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
values="1 0 0 0 0
        0 1 0 0 0
        0 0 1 0 0
        0 0 0 .3 0" result="outline2"/>`

Этот фильтр умножает альфа-компонент контура на 0,3, поэтому он выглядит серым, а не сплошным черным.

`<feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over" result="output"/>`

Наконец, добавьте этот вывод в исходное изображение.

Источник: [SVG: border outline for group of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694939/7394871) @squeamish ossifrage

---

---

*Прим. переводчика*

На мой взгляд эта тема интересна, открывает широкие горизонты для творчества и может иметь практическое применение.

- применение группы фильтров дает возможность получить контур любой
  сложности без применения патчей и стандартных команд обводки
- Изменяя параметры фильтра `feColorMatrix` можно  получить практически любой цвет контура
- применение фильтра `feMorphology` позволяет изменять ширину обводки и
  зазор между основной фигурой и обводкой

*Пример получения зелёного контура*

Для этого выставляем параметры фильтра  `feColorMatrix`

`<feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>`

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="12" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="4" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="orange" />
    <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Пример получения красного контура с расширением обводки*

Для этого расширяем радиус действия у фильтра

`<feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="18" result="e1" />`

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="18" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="orange" />
    <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Пример изменения контура при изменении набора внутренних фигур*

Просто добавим в группу элементов вторую линию и посмотрим как автоматически изменится обводка, формируемая фильтрами

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="18" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="orange" />
    <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
 <line x1="50" y1="200" x2="200" y2="50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Примеры анимации контуров сформированных фильтрами

1. Анимация контура при изменении длины внутренней линии

Команда на изменение длины линии:

```
<polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="4" >  
    <animate attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 200,50;125,125 200,50;125,125 125,125" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"  repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
</polyline>
```

Изменяется только конфигурация линии, а контур автоматически отслеживает эти изменения

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="18" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="orange" />
    <polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="purple" stroke-width="4" >
 <animate attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 200,200;125,125 200,200;125,125 125,125" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
 </polyline>
  <polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="violet" stroke-width="4" > 
 <animate attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 50,50;125,125 50,50;125,125 125,125" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</polyline>

 <polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="4" >
 <animate attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 50,200;125,125 50,200;125,125 125,125" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</polyline>
  <polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="4" > 
 <animate attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 200,50;125,125 200,50;125,125 125,125" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"  repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
 </polyline>
 
 
  </g>
</svg>
```

2. Анимация изменения ширины строки

Для этого добавляется команда анимации изменения ширины строки от `4px` до `90px`

```
<circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="yellow" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="14 6.41" > 
   <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="4;90;90;4;4;90" dur="7s" begin="click" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive">   
</circle>
```

*Начало анимации - клик по фигуре*

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="10" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0.5 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
    <text x="110" y="100" font-size="18">click</text> 
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)" fill-opacity="0.8">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="yellow" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="14 6.41" > 
 <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="4;90;90;4;4;90" dur="7s" begin="click" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
  </circle>  

  </g>
</svg>
```

3. Анимация вращения линии

Добавляются две команды анимации: изменение длины линии и вращение линии:

```
<polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="purple" stroke-width="7" >
    <animate id="poly" attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 50,50" dur="2s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="1" />   
    <animateTransform id="rotate1" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 125 125;720 125 125;0 125 125" begin="poly.end-1s" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="12s" />
</polyline>
<circle cx="125" cy="125" r="8" fill="#3196C9" stroke="purple" stroke-width="2" />
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="16" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="9" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0.3 0
                             0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="#AAD0A0" stroke="#4A8ECD" stroke-width="2" />
 
    <polyline points="125,125 125,125" stroke="purple" stroke-width="7" >
 <animate id="poly" attributeName="points" values="125,125 125,125;125,125 50,50" dur="2s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="1" />   
 <animateTransform id="rotate1" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 125 125;720 125 125;0 125 125" begin="poly.end-1s" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="12s" />
 </polyline>
  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="8" fill="#3196C9" stroke="purple" stroke-width="2" />
 
  </g>
</svg>
```

4. Анимация `stroke-dasharray`

   ```
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="yellow" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="20.41 0" > 
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="20.41 0;0 20.41;10 10.41;20.41 0" begin="click" dur="3.5s"  repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>
   ```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="6" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0.5 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <text x="110" y="90" font-size="20">click</text> 
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)" fill-opacity="0.7">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="yellow" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="20.41 0" > 
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="20.41 0;0 20.41;10 10.41;20.41 0" begin="click" dur="3.5s"  repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle> 
  
  </g>
</svg>
```

5. Анимация `stroke-width`, `stroke-dasharray`

   ```
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="yellow" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="74" stroke-dasharray="1 19.41" > 
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 20.41;16 4.41;16 4.41; 0 20.41" begin="click" dur="3.5s"  repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   ```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="6" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0.5 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <text x="110" y="90" font-size="20">click</text> 
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)" fill-opacity="0.7">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="65" fill="yellow" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="74" stroke-dasharray="1 19.41" > 
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 20.41;16 4.41;16 4.41; 0 20.41" begin="click" dur="3.5s"  repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle> 
  
  </g>
</svg>
```

6. *Пример построения графика*

Используется анимация увеличения вертикальных линий и автоматически формируемая фильтрами рамка.

```html
<svg width="80%" height="80%" viewBox="0 80 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="0%" y="0%" width="500" height="500">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="12" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="3" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0.4 0
                             0 0 0 0.4 0
                             0 0 0 0.4 0
                             0 0 0 0.8 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    
    <polyline points="50,450 50,450" stroke="purple" stroke-width="55" >
 <animate id="an1" 
    attributeName="points"
    values="50,450 50,450;50,450 50,200"
    dur="1s"
    begin="0s"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze" />  
 </polyline> 
   <polyline points="110,450 110,450" stroke="gold" stroke-width="55" >
 <animate id="an2"
    attributeName="points"
    values="110,450 110,450;110,450 110,150"
    dur="1s"
    begin="an1.end"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze" />  
 </polyline> 
 <polyline points="170,450 170,450" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="55" >
 <animate id="an3"
    attributeName="points"
    values="170,450 170,450;170,450 170,130"
    dur="1s"
    begin="an2.end"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze" />  
 </polyline> 
 <polyline id="an4" points="230,450 230,450" stroke="green" stroke-width="55" >
 <animate
    attributeName="points"
    values="230,450 230,450;230,450 230,70;230,450 230,220"    dur="1s"
    begin="an3.end"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze" />  
 </polyline>
</g>  
 
</svg>
```