# Проблема с прозрачным текстом при иммитации обводки с помощью псевдоэлементов

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, filter

Мне трудно поверить, что не существует стандартного и простого (и независимого от браузера) способа поместить эффект обводки вокруг текста с помощью CSS.

Есть `-webkit-text-stroke`, но по какой-то странной причине, обводка сосредоточена вокруг границы текста, а не за ее пределами. Как показано [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/text-stroke-stuck-middle/#article-header-id-0).

Я пытаюсь реализовать обходной путь, основанный на этой [идее](https://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/), который помещает заштрихованный текст в псевдоэлемент за исходным незаштрихованным текстом. Я продемонстрировал это в этом [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsnkad5/) со следующим кодом:

```js
var jQueryAttr = function(selector, attr, setterFunction) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el, i) => {
    el.setAttribute(attr, setterFunction.call(el, i, attr));
  });
};

jQueryAttr('.myclass', 'data-myclass', function(index, attr) {
  return this.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: none;
}

.basic {
  color: rgba(186, 218, 85, 1);
  font: 2.5em Georgia, serif;
}

.myclass {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

.myclass::before {
  content: attr(data-myclass);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}

.anotherclass {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<p class="basic">Text without any stroke</p>
<p class="myclass basic">Text with outer stroke</p>
<p class="anotherclass basic">Without the trick applied</p>
```

Это работает нормально, за исключением того, что если сам текст имеет некоторую прозрачность, то вы видите темный штрих под ним, как показано в этом [варианте](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsnkad5/1/).

Как вы можете видеть, черный цвет от обведенного элемента просачивается в текст (в верхней строке).

Так есть ли еще один хитрый способ решить эту проблему?

Я предполагаю, что возможно добавить еще один псевдоэлемент между слоем с обводкой и слоем без обводки. С чистым белым текстом или с тем, чтобы соответствовать фону. Но я хотел бы применить эту технику в контексте, где я не не знаю цвет фона заранее, например, где это накладывается на произвольное выбранное пользователем изображение. По этой причине, в приведенном выше примере я установил значение фона `body`.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54999526/7394871

Comment: Предлагайте свои варианты решения. Тема богата возможностями для новых ответов.

Answer (score 3):

### SVG решение

Самым простым и с лучшей поддержкой браузеров может быть SVG.

Вы можете настроить примерно то же самое, что вы сделали с `:: before`, с той разницей, что версия с обводным фоном может иметь маску, которая позволит видеть только внешнюю линию.  Оттуда вы можете просто добавить копию того же текста поверх, и вы сможете применить непрозрачность, как вы хотите, как для обводки и заливки:

```css
body{
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1051);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
}
svg {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.textStroke {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 12px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
.visibleText {
  fill: rgba(186, 218, 85, 1);
  transition: fill-opacity .5s linear;
}
.visibleText:hover {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="350">
  <defs>
    <!-- we type it only once -->
    <text x="10" y="55" id="txt">Text with outline</text>
    <mask id="mymask">
      <!-- white => visible, black => tansparent -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="450" height="70" fill="#FFF"></rect>
      <use xlink:href="#txt" fill="#000"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <!-- our stroked text, with the mask -->
  <use xlink:href="#txt" mask="url(#mymask)" class="textStroke"/>
  <!-- fill version -->
  <use xlink:href="#txt" class="visibleText"/>
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55144568/7394871): @Kaiido

Answer (score 2):

- Вот идея, где вы можете применить `mix-blend-modeё` в сочетании с
  `text-shadow`, чтобы приблизить это. Самое сложное - отрегулировать
  тень на тот случай, если вы хотите широкую строку обводки:

```css
.text > span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    2px 0  0px #000,
    0 2px 0px #000,
    2px 2px 0px #000,
    -2px 0 0px #000,
    0 -2px 0px #000,
    -2px -2px 0px #000,
    -2px 2px 0px #000,
    2px -2px 0px #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span>Some text here</span></div>
```

- Использование CSS-переменной, вероятно, облегчит настройку:

```css
.text > span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    var(--s,2px) 0  var(--c,0) #000,
    0 var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) 0 var(--c,0) #000,
    0 calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red, blue);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span>Some text here</span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:4px;--c:2px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1067)"><span>Some text here</span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:6px;--c:4px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1051)"><span>Some text here</span></div>
```

- Если вам нужен прозрачный цвет для текста, вы можете продублировать
  его, используя псевдоэлемент:

```css
.text > span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.text > span::before,
.text > span::after {
  content:attr(data-text);
}
.text > span::before {
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    var(--s,2px) 0  var(--c,0) #000,
    0 var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) 0 var(--c,0) #000,
    0 calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
.text > span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:rgba(0,255,0,0.4); 
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red, blue);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span data-text="Some text here"></span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:4px;--c:2px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1063)"><span data-text="Some text here"></span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:6px;--c:4px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1051)"><span data-text="Some text here"></span></div>
```

[Источник ответа:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001610/7394871) @Temani Afif

Answer (score 1):

### Решение с помощью SVG фильтров

Для получения обводки вокруг текста, можно использовать комбинированный SVG фильтр, состоящий из последовательно применяемых фильтров: `feMorphology`, `feComposite` и `feColorMatrix`.
Решение универсальное, его можно использовать для любых графических объектов.

[Пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/811296/28748)

```css
body{
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1061);
  background-size:cover;
  font-family: serif;
  
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 350 350" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="5" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="2" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0.1
                             0 0 0 0 0.2
                             0 0 0 0 0.2
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <text x="10" y="100"  stroke-width="1" fill="#1D3A56"  font-family="serif" font-size="30" font-weight="700" > Text with outline </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```